# Get the current month and year in moment js

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I'd like to get the current month and year in moment.js ex: September-2020

I've tried moment() and it shows the hole date in numbers only

Comment: Hi, Please try exploring below URL, it has all the information regarding moment.js library. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in right format parameter to get the desired results. Please check here for more details https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

In your case, try this out

```js
let check = moment("2020/09/25", "YYYY/MM/DD");
console.log(check.format("MMMM-YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```